# Ruby app running on Sinatra using HAML, can't access files in uploads directory?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have a Ruby app which is an Image Resizer. It uses the RMagick gem to do this. The app asks the user to upload a file, and then resizes it and saves the newly generated file.

It seems that Sinatra by default puts all uploaded files into the 'uploads' directory, and the newly generated file also seems to be saved there. I am assuming this is default behavior, not sure how to change this, but it isn't an immediate problem at the moment (although if you know how to do this, that would be appreciated too).

Now, in my 'success.haml' page which is displayed after the file is generated correctly, I am trying to display the newly generated image with a simple img tag. The path to the file is found in @filepath, so when I did:

```
%img(src=@filepath)
```

the HTML rendered (when inspected using Firebug) is correctly showing

```
<img src="uploads/filename.jpg">
```

and this file does indeed exist in my folder structure. However, the image appears broken.

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your public dir point to? Is `uploads` in it?

Comment: So based on your question, I made an 'uploads' directory inside public and then put the image in there, and it was successfully accessed.

Comment: Should I post it as an answer then? :)

Comment: Please do so I can accept it and future visitors to this page can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative urls (`uploads/filename.jpg`) are called so because they are relative to web root. In Sinatra this is the public folder. By default it's located in your app directory and called `public`. But you can override that.

```
set :public_folder, 'my_root' # this will make my_root dir the web root.
```

So, to make your uploads visible to the internet, put them into your public folder.

[Read this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) for more Sinatra settings and customizations.